# Android looks for layout instead of layout-large when Activity is started for the second time

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to provide different layouts depending on whether the app runs on a smartphone or on a tablet. Therefore I put different layout definitions in `layout-normal` resp. `layout-large`.

During testing on tablet I run into a the following exception when the associated activity is started **for the second time**:

```
09-06 13:28:43.640: E/AndroidRuntime(26260): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030005
09-06 13:28:43.640: E/AndroidRuntime(26260):    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1010)
09-06 13:28:43.640: E/AndroidRuntime(26260):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2088)
09-06 13:28:43.640: E/AndroidRuntime(26260):    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:849)
09-06 13:28:43.640: E/AndroidRuntime(26260):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:389)
09-06 13:28:43.640: E/AndroidRuntime(26260):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
09-06 13:28:43.640: E/AndroidRuntime(26260):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:245)
09-06 13:28:43.640: E/AndroidRuntime(26260):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1786)
09-06 13:28:43.640: E/AndroidRuntime(26260):    ... 11 more
```

When the Activity is started for the first time everything is fine and the layout is inflated correctly. The error only occurs after the Activity has been finished and gets restarted from the previous Activity on the back stack.

I could reproduce the problem on Samsung Galaxy Tab running Android 3.2 and in the emulator for Android 3.2 and 4.1. The layout is loaded via `Activity.setContentView(int resId)`, so there is no magic at this point. Furthermore the resource ID that gets logged in the stacktrace (`#0x7f030005`) corresponds to the id of the root layout in `R.layout` that is given to `Activity.setContentView(int resId)`.

If I copy the layout from the `layout-large` to the `layout` folder and change the background color in the copy the exception is not thrown but the unspecific version from `layout` with the modified background color is loaded.

In the Manifest I already configured the supported screens

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Does anybody have an idea of how to fix this?

Comment: in which device you are running.

Comment: Running on Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1, but the error also occurs in emulator.

Comment: actually samsung 10.1 is not larger its xlarge you need to supply layout-xlarge.

Comment: Yes, I know that but large resources should be used instead if no xlarge resources are available and so it does when the layout is inflated for the first time ("... the system will use resources designed for a screen smaller than the current screen if there are no resources that better match (for example, a large-size screen will use normal-size screen resources if necessary). ...", http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch)

Comment: I did some further testing and it seems that it has nothing to do with `large` vs. `xlarge`. I copied the layout into `layout-normal`, `layout-large` and `layout-xlarge` and assigned different background colors to distinguish them. At the first start the right one from `layout-xlarge` is inflated. But on the second start I still get the error unless I put another layout in the `layout` folder without any size qualifier.

Comment: its seems like an strange think can you send you project I will test it.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not provide it out of the box, because it belongs to a customer project. I can shrink it down into a minimal example but this will take some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The origin of the error was in an external library I used:

They were constructing an object subclassed from `android.content.res.Resources` to fake an in-memory resource. The `Resources` object's construction required an `AssetManager` as one of the parameters, which has been obtained using the Activity's `getAssets()` method. It seems that this was corrupting the resources.

It seems that the correct way to construct a `Resource` object is by passing in a brand new `AssetManager` instance (which also means using the private AssetManager constructor).